# I got an error when using mkdir command with " ! " - Python

Tags: python, tensorflow

There is a SyntaxError message when using mkdir command. I already import os library.
I want to run !mkdir. I have no idea because I already implemented the correct path format. please kindly help me.

```
import cv2 
import time
import uuid
import os

IMAGES_PATH = 'Tensorflow/workspace/images/collectedimages'

lables = ['hello', 'thanks', 'yes', 'no', 'iloveyou']
number_imgs = 15

for lable in lables:

    !mkdir {'Tensorflow\workspace\images\collectedimages\\'+lable}

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    print('Collecting imagess for {}'.format(lables))
    time.sleep(5)
    for imgnum in range(number_imgs):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        imgname = os.path.join(IMAGES_PATH, lable, lable+'.'+'{}.jpg'.format(str(uuid.uuid1())))
        cv2.imwrite(imgname, frame)
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        time.sleep()

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    
    cap.release()
```

Comment: Use https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkdir. `!` is not correct syntax but you can use as command line in Jupyter.

Comment: How can implement the same in phython? Can you help me.

Comment: Python by itself doesn't have `!mkdir`. I'm guessing you are trying to ask about iPython (or one of the projects which uses it, such as Jupyter) but as it stands, this is unclear and unanswerable.

Answer (score 1):

Use `os` module to create directory instead of using shell commands.

```
import os
  
directory = "<your_directory_name>"
parent_dir = "T:/<parent_directory>/"
path = os.path.join(parent_dir, directory)
  
os.mkdir(path)

print("Directory '% s' created" % directory)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on windows, then you can use the below code:

```
import cv2 
import time
import uuid
import os

IMAGES_PATH = 'Tensorflow\workspace\images\collectedimages'

lables = ['hello', 'thanks', 'yes', 'no', 'iloveyou']
number_imgs = 15

for lable in labels:

   os.mkdir('Tensorflow\workspace\images\collectedimages\\'+lable)

   cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
   print('Collecting imagess for {}'.format(lables))
   time.sleep(5)
   for imgnum in range(number_imgs):
      ret, frame = cap.read()
      imgname = os.path.join(IMAGES_PATH, label, 
      lable+'.'+'{}.jpg'.format(str(uuid.uuid1())))
      cv2.imwrite(imgname, frame)
      cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
      time.sleep()

      if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
         break

   cap.release()
```

If you are using ubuntu:

change `!mkdir {'Tensorflow\workspace\images\collectedimages\\'+lable}`
to `os.system('sudo mkdir Tensorflow/workspace/images/collectedimages//'+label)`

Answer (score -3):

## If you are running on windows, then you can use the below code:

```
import cv2 
import time
import uuid
import os

IMAGES_PATH = 'Tensorflow/workspace/images/collectedimages'

lables = ['hello', 'thanks', 'yes', 'no', 'iloveyou']
number_imgs = 15

for lable in lables:

    path = 'Tensorflow\workspace\images\collectedimages\\'
    os.mkdir(path+lable)

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    print('Collecting imagess for {}'.format(lable))
    time.sleep(5)
    for imgnum in range(number_imgs):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        imgname = os.path.join(IMAGES_PATH, lable, lable+'.'+'{}.jpg'.format(str(uuid.uuid1())))
        cv2.imwrite(imgname, frame)
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        time.sleep()

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
```

Comment: Hello, and thanks for the help! It might be worth just highlighting the change you made (`os.mkdir` rather than bare `mkdir`) and making sure the code is formatted correctly!